# Why this code in Javascript for swapping 2 elements in an array does not work?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wanted to make a function that swaps 2 elements of an array in Javascript, so I created this piece of code:

```
let arrayOne = ["elementA","elementB","elementC","elementD","elementE","elementF","elementG","elementH","elementI"];

function swapThatFails(element1,element2) {
    arrayOne[arrayOne.indexOf(element1)] = element2;
    arrayOne[arrayOne.indexOf(element2)] = element1;
    console.log("arrayOne = ",arrayOne);
}

swapThatFails ("elementA", "elementC");
```

However, it makes no change at all in the original array.

I managed to make it work by obtaining apart the indexes of the array I want to swap:

```
let arrayTwo = ["elementA","elementB","elementC","elementD","elementE","elementF","elementG","elementH","elementI"];

function swapThatWorks(element1,element2) {
    let index1 = arrayTwo.indexOf(element1);
    let index2 = arrayTwo.indexOf(element2);
    arrayTwo[index1] = element2;
    arrayTwo[index2] = element1;
    console.log("arrayTwo = ",arrayTwo);
}

swapThatWorks ("elementA", "elementC");
```

To me, they both are the same apart from the fact that the second makes it in 2 steps so it looks easier to be understood.

Why the first one does not work but the second one does?

```js
let arrayOne = ["elementA","elementB","elementC","elementD","elementE","elementF","elementG","elementH","elementI"];

let arrayTwo = ["elementA","elementB","elementC","elementD","elementE","elementF","elementG","elementH","elementI"];

function swapThatFails(element1,element2) {
    arrayOne[arrayOne.indexOf(element1)] = element2;
    arrayOne[arrayOne.indexOf(element2)] = element1;
    console.log("arrayOne = ",arrayOne);
  }

function swapThatWorks(element1,element2) {
    let index1 = arrayTwo.indexOf(element1);
    let index2 = arrayTwo.indexOf(element2);
    arrayTwo[index1] = element2;
    arrayTwo[index2] = element1;
    console.log("arrayTwo = ",arrayTwo);
  }
  
swapThatFails ("elementA", "elementC");
swapThatWorks ("elementA", "elementC");
```

Comment: `arrayOne[arrayOne.indexOf(element1)] = element2;` finds the first index of `element2` (which is zero) and updates it with `element2`.  `arrayOne[arrayOne.indexOf(element2)] = element1;` finds the **first index** of `element2` (which is now zero) and updates it with `element1`. So the code does `arrayOne[0] = "elementC"; arrayOne[0] = "elementA";` resulting in net no change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider this

```
function swapThatFails(element1,element2) {
  arrayOne[arrayOne.indexOf(element1)] = element2;
  arrayOne[arrayOne.indexOf(element2)] = element1;
  console.log("arrayOne = ",arrayOne);
}
```

Suppose the array is `['a','b']` and you call your flawed function with `swapThatFails('a', 'b')`.

First you search for `element1` and put `element2` in there

```
arrayOne[arrayOne.indexOf(element1)] = element2;
```

Your array becomes `['b','b']`

Then you search for `element2` and put `element1` there. But the array is already modified! The first occurence of `element2` is not its **original** position but the new one, the one that has just been replaced in previous step.

Thus this

```
  arrayOne[arrayOne.indexOf(element2)] = element1;
```

finds `b` as the first element and replaces it with `a`. And you get `['a','b']`. It's not what you expected!

If on the other hand you first search for elements, get correct indexes and then replace elements, it works as expected.

Comment: Sure! This explains perfectly why it sometimes worked and sometimes did not. i.e.: `swapThatFails ("elementC", "elementA")` actually worked but `swapThatFails ("elementA", "elementC")` didn't.